# angularjs pass index of array into ng-change function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use ng-select to populate my options, but I want to pass the selected index, what should be in the ng-change function?

like if the user selected `b` I will get `1` which is the second index of the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/kqcrL5j3/

```
<select 
            ng-options="p as a for a in alpa"
            ng-model="selected" ng-change="detectChange('what to pass index here?')"></select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code like this,

```
<select ng-options="a for a in alpa" ng-model="selected" ng-init="selected='a'" ng-change="detectChange(selected)"></select>
```

You can pass the whole selected object and find the index like this,

```
  $scope.detectChange = function(selected_index){
       var indexno =  $scope.alpa.indexOf(selected_index );
       console.log(indexno)
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqcrL5j3/4/)